# need help with date in C# + access

Tags: c#, winforms, date

in access 2007: i have field type date - in `shortDate` format

in my computer: i have region date `dd/MM/yyyy`

in my C# program: in the DateTimePiker i have `format: short`, `CustomFormat: dd/MM/yyyy`

the problem is: when i insert the value from DateTimePiker to access i got it in wrong format

for example:

i insert in DateTimePiker: 03/08/2007

i get in access: 08/03/2007

i insert the data like this: `"insert into MyTbl (MyDate) values (#" + dt_From.Value + "#)"`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call DateTime.ToOADate() (eg, `shortDate.ToOADate()`), which converts the date to an OLE Automation date

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your date format to access format using this

```
   DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
   string str = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
   string str1 = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Here in your code you can apply this for dt_From.Value

Comment: i try this, but still when i insert 03/08/2010 i get in access 08/03/2010